# Python: datetime.strtime does not return expected value

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

What's wrong with this code?

```py
    while True:
        time.sleep(2)
        current_time = datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M")
        if current_time == "9:21":
            driver.find_element_by_id("schedule_session").click()
            break
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At 9:21, you will get a value of `09:21`, not `9:21`.
https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes